# Reading Elements from VCARD

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, vb.net

I simply want to read one element from the below regex

```
 BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:2.1FN:Peter StoddartADR:My School (BranchName)TEL;CELL:00129222273645EMAIL;HOME;INTERNET:abc@gmail.comREV:3757END:VCARD
```

and i only want the value `REV:3757`

I tried multiple regex but didnt got the success

```
\BREV\w*\b
```

which return `REV:3757END` but i only want 3757

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookarounds:

```
string text = "BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:2.1FN:Peter StoddartADR:My School (BranchName)TEL;CELL:00129222273645EMAIL;HOME;INTERNET:abc@gmail.comREV:3757END:VCARD";
var reg = new Regex(@"(?<=\BREV:)\d+(?=END)");
var match = reg.Match(text);
Console.WriteLine(match);
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/SPczHO)

Or if you don't mind using capture groups:

```
string text = "BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:2.1FN:Peter StoddartADR:My School (BranchName)TEL;CELL:00129222273645EMAIL;HOME;INTERNET:abc@gmail.comREV:3757END:VCARD";
var reg = new Regex(@"\BREV:(\d+)END");
var match = reg.Match(text);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/vh6tgE)

Comment: "if you don't mind using" - are capture groups a bad thing / bad practice then?

Comment: @Rup Some people don't like using capture groups, others don't like using lookarounds... Can't please both categories of people, so I give the options. Both methods have slightly different implications so...

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this :

```
REV\:\d+
```

this will give you the value `REV:3757` only

now you can use a negative lookahead to give the value of the number.

```
(?<=REV:)\d+
```

this will give you only the number `3757`

Answer (score 1):

This returned the Revision for me. have a try.

```
public class Program
{

    const string input = "BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:2.1FN:Peter StoddartADR:My School (BranchName)TEL;CELL:00129222273645EMAIL;HOME;INTERNET:abc@gmail.comREV:3757END:VCARD";        

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Regex expression = new Regex(@"REV:(?<SearchID>[\d]+)END");
        var match = expression.Match(input);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["SearchID"].Value);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
string result = Regex.Replace(searchText, "(.+\\BREV\\w*\\b:([\\d]+).+)", "$2");
```